# Migrate Tomcat Project to Jboss and configure JBoss AS in NetBeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, configuration, jboss, facelets

I have a project that I used to run in Tomcat Server Application 7.0. Now I have to migrate it to Jboss 5.1.

What is the configuration that I have to change in my project?

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.labcon</groupId>
<artifactId>Catalogo2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Catalogo2</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

  <repositories>


  <repository>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <id>jsf20</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library Library[jsf20]</name>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <id>jstl11</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library Library[jstl11]</name>
    </repository>
    <repository>  
        <id>prime-repo</id>  
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
        <layout>default</layout>  
    </repository> 


        <repository>
            <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.15</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1B</version>
  </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
  <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1</version>
 </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>commons-io</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
<version>2.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>rome</groupId>
<artifactId>rome</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.7</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
<groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
<artifactId>itext</artifactId>
<version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
         <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

    <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.3.2</version>
               <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>
        Resource Servlet
    </servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>
        org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet
    </servlet-class>  
</servlet> 

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>    
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>      
   <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class> 
</filter>   

<filter-mapping>    
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>  
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
</filter-mapping>
```

Another problem is that I installed JBoss 5.1 and managed to run it in netbeans separatly, but when I choose to run the project, the option: JBoss doesn't appear to me.

Comment: Please, i need this answer fast

Answer (score 1):

So here's your "fast" answer ;-)

We're 2 years older and JBoss AS 5 was obsolted by JBoss AS 7 and WildFly 8.
So I assume today's readers want to migrate to that.

There are two tools which help with migration to JBoss AS 7 / WildFly 8 / EAP 6:

1) [JBoss SwanLoom](https://github.com/OndraZizka/jboss-migration/wiki/) - automated migration tool aimed to server configuration migration.

2) [JBoss WindUp](http://windup.jboss.org/) - a reporting tool aimed to application migration - deployment descriptors etc.

And finally, there's a new site dedicated to JBoss migration: http://www.jboss.org/migration/ , where you can find all the migration guides to do the migration manually.

Regarding `pom.xml`, you'll have to kick out all the deps which are already contained in JBoss AS. API's may stay but only as compile-time dependency (should not end up in the .war).

Depending on to which extent you want to migrate, you might also want to drop Spring entirely and replace it with services provided by JBoss AS, and connect parts of your app using CDI annotations.

Regarding JBoss AS in NetBeans, there was built-in support for AS 5 for ages, at least since 6.x, and since 7.3.1, it should also support AS 7.